# Flyway switches to Teams edition without any teams features being used

Tags: flyway

I have recently started using the baseline and repeatable migrations in my app. Although I don't seem to be using any teams-edition features, yet flyway somehow switches automatically to the Teams edition instead of Community edition, and shows a message :

Flyway Teams Edition 8.2.0 by Redgate
Flyway Teams features are enabled by default for the next 27 days. Learn more at https://rd.gt/3A4IWym

Previously we had eight versioned migrations **V1__xxxx.sql** to **V8__xxxx.sql**

Now we have made the following changes :

1. All the eight migrations, plus some other init scripts have been combined into a single migration **V1__seed-data.sql**
2. Repeatable migrations have been put into **R__xxxx.sql**
3. Some placeholders have been placed into the **flyway.conf** like : fileflyway.placeholders.app_db_name=${APP_DB_NAME}

For our existing Production DB, which was already migrated till V8, we have Dropped the flyway_schema_history table and used the "**flyway baseline**" command with an environment variable **FLYWAY_BASELINE_VERSION=1**

After this, the flyway_schema_history shows us this result :

[image]

But after these changes, we are seeing the "Teams edition" message as above.

Earlier it used to show :
Flyway Community Edition 8.2.0 by Redgate

I am quite sure looking at the flyway documentation that we haven't used any Teams edition features. https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/commandline/baseline

Now I have 2 questions :

1. What caused flyway to switch to Teams edition without teams features being used?
2. What happens once the trial period ends? Does flyway block all our migrations in the future unless we buy the license?

Answer (score 0):

Update Flyway to the latest version; the "Auto trial" feature created the "Teams edition" message you're seeing here, and was removed in Flyway 8.4.3 - [release notes](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/releaseNotes#8.4.3).

Comment: Thanks for answering this. Do you know if the current version of Flyway 8.2.0 automatically downgrades to the Community edition once the Teams trial has expired?

Comment: Nothing about the version changes, except that if you try to call a Teams edition feature (undo, dry-run etc) after the 28 day trial period you'll be asked for a license key; all of Community edition features (info, migrate etc) remain intact and will run without issue.